# How can I specify the elements of a matrix from the interface using input in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm using the matrix extension in my model and I'd like to be able to change the elements of this matrix through the GUI rather than hard coding them. It looks like this at the moment:

```
extensions [matrix]
globals [test_matrix]

to setup
   set test_matrix matrix:from-row-list [[
     1
     2
     3
     4
    ]]
end
```

But if I try to set the values using the `Input` function on the GUI I get an error that it 'expected a literal value.'

```
 set test_matrix matrix:from-row-list [[
         element1
         element2
         element3
         element4
        ]]
```

Comment: When you do `[ 1 2 3 4 ]` in the first section you're creating a list literal, and NetLogo only allows literal values in list literals (numbers, strings, other list literals).  To make a list with non-literal (variable or expression) values use the `list` primitive:  `matrix:from-row-list (list (list element1 element2 element3 element4))`

Comment: @Jasper, you should turn that comment into a proper answer so that it can be accepted and the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `[ 1 2 3 4 ]` in the first section you're creating a list literal, and NetLogo only allows constant values in list literals (numbers, strings, other list literals). See [the Lists section of the programming guide for more](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#lists).

To make a list with non-literal (variable or expression) values use [the `list` primitive](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#list):

```
set test_matrix matrix:from-row-list (list (list 
  element1 
  element2 
  element3 
  element4
))
```

See [the FAQ entry](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#im-trying-to-make-a-list-why-do-i-keep-getting-the-error-expected-a-constant) as well.